# Channels of Practical Interest

Tags: it.information-theory

Are there channels of practical interest whose capacity achieving probability distributions belong to a parametric family of probability measures?

Specifically, suppose $ \theta= (\theta_1 \theta_2 .... \theta_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a parameter vector such that the set $E = \{ P_\theta | \theta \in \mathbb{R}^n \} $ is a collection of probabiliy measures over a finite alphabet set $X$. Are there channels $(X,Y,P_{Y|X})$ and parametric families of probability measures $E$ whose capacity achieving distribution is an element of $E$?